# Error on published ASP.NET core site: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

My webb app works fine when run from Visual Studio, but when I publish and try to load a page, I get:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List assemblies)

I've been stuck on this for quite a while. I've attempted to apply the various workarounds in the thread https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2981, but none of them have worked.

My csproj file is pasted below. I'm not sure what other information would be useful:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-CrowdQuery2-8C668DB3-5C80-4D9E-851D-2434D0CDA7E9</UserSecretsId>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: know that it's old, but for me this issue comment became really helpful https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37760#issuecomment-518783156

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've been having the same issue using Microsoft Azure.

The solution in this case was to clean up the `wwwroot` folder in our web app using Kudu (**Development Tools -> Advanced Options**), because there were some old DLLs still left from before the upgrade to .NET Core 2.1, because .NET Core 1 publishes the DLLs to the `wwwroot` folder, whereas in 2.1, the DLLs are loaded from a global store.

After having completely emptied the `wwwroot` folder, and redeploying the app, the error was resolved and the app ran as expected.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, as it's close to what I finally figured out (but forgot to circle back and add to the conversation). In my case, it was on the hosting provider, but it involved deleting old DLLs that the application must have been picking up instead of the right ones.

Comment: Just a note regarding how to empty the wwwroot folder using PowerShell in Kudu. Firstly, ensure that your app is stopped. Then, use this command to empty wwwroot: `Remove-Item D:\home\site\wwwroot\* -Recurse -Force` (or replace the path to wherever your wwwroot is located).

Answer (score 1):

I had to

(1)

Edit .csproj and add

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>False</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(2)

Change the publish "Target Runtime" to "win-x64" (it was previously x86). I don't know why this is required, because my project properties -> Platform target is "Any CPU".

(I have two other similar websites in the same solution, neither of those .csproj files require that line, and both are still publishing to x86).